# Windows Server 2003 vs 2008 & ADAM vs AD LDS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, adam, ad-lds

Comparing Window Server 2003 to 2008, I know that ADAM (active directory application mode) has been replaced with AD LDS (active directory lightweight directory services).  I am just wondering, if there are any other changes than just the name that I should be aware of?  Does it work the same way?  On Window Server 2008, AD LDS is installed with just adding the role service of AD LDS while ADAM can be installed w/the optional component manager?

Thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897400.aspx for the details of the enhancements.